# Why can I not save files with firefox?

Tags: firefox, directory

Am using Firefox 18 (also tried 19b2 from launchpad repository). When trying to save a file or website to a specific directory, I get error message

```
... could not be saved, because you cannot change the contents of that folder.
Change the folder properties and try again, or try saving in a different location.
```

In firefox error console I can see

```
Error: NS_ERROR_FAILURE: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIWebBrowserPersist.saveDocument]
```

The directory that am trying to save to is a NFS volume. It is in my own username and it has 750 permission. Files inside have permission 660.

These below can save, edit and delete files from the directory:

- Chrome 25.0.1364.36 beta
- KDE Dolphin 2.1
- Firefox 17, 18, 18.1, 19b1, 19b2 (downloaded from
  https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/)

So the problem is only in the release from ubuntu/debian/repository, not from mozillas own release of firefox. I have a clean firefox profile (deleted ~/.mozilla directory).

Please advice.

Comment: I can offer 1 suggestion based on your permission: maybe firefox saves files as "other" and the other browsers as your user. Simple test: change permissions on folders to 775 and files to 664 and try to save a file.

Comment: Well, I have a problem. The problem is gone. I can now suddenly save with firefox version from ubuntu repository. Really strange. I have had this problem for months and now suddenly when I take my time to troubleshoot this and it disappears.